# 2 sequences of R.Vs equal and Convergence $L_1$

Tags: probability, general-topology, limits

On a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$.

Let $(X_n)_n, (Y_n)_n$ two sequences of random variables.

*Question :*

If $X_n=Y_n$ for every $n$ and $X_n$ converges $L_1$ to $X$ then $Y_n$ converges to $X$ ?

I think yes since : $\forall \eta>0,\ \exists N>0, \forall n\geq N,\ $
$$
\mathbb E \mid Y_n-X \mid\leq\mathbb E \mid Y_n-X_n \mid+\mathbb E \mid X_n-X \mid \\
=0+\mathbb E \mid X_n-X \mid<\eta
$$

*However I have a counter example :*

If we take $X_n=\epsilon$ (is a Bernouilli$(1/2,\{-1,1\})$ for instance) and $Y_n=X_n 1_{1/n>0}$ then $X_n=Y_n$ **but** $Y_n$ converges $L_1$ to $0\neq \epsilon$.

**Where does my proof (or counter-example) is flawed ?**

Comment: Well, $Y_n$ does not converge to $0$. Also, if $X_n = Y_n$ and $X_n \to X$, then trivially $Y_n =X_n \to X$ as well.

Comment: In wich sense $X_n=Y_n$? In distribution? in the sense that for every $\omega\in\Omega$, $X_n(\omega)=Y_n(\omega)$?

Comment: @PhoemueX $Y_n$ converges $L_1$ to $0$ : $\mathbb E \mid Y_n - 0 \mid \leq 1_{1/n>0}\mathbb E \mid \epsilon\mid\leq K.1_{1/n>0}\rightarrow 0$

Comment: @RobertoCabal in the $2^{nd}$ sense : $\forall \omega\in\Omega,\ X_n(\omega)=Y_n(\omega)$

Comment: @the-owner  In that sense the question it totally meaningless  and it is obvious from definition of limit.

Comment: @the-owner: 1_{1/n >0}$ does **not** converge to $0$. It is always one.